# CMAKE, SDL2 and OPENGL: Program binary is too big

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, sdl-2

I use CMAKE to link a program to SDL2, OpenGL and I compile tinyxml2 as a shared library. The resulting program binary is 1.4 mb but there's barely 1k lines of code in the program. I suspect some library is statically linked. I'd prefer they are linked as shared libraries. I tried with debug symbols on and off with:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .
```

and off:

```
cmake .
```

and resulting binaries are still 1.4 mb each, which is weird because debug should be bigger. Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(ProjectName)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-find-scripts")

aux_source_directory(. SRC_ROOT)
aux_source_directory(./extlib SRC_EXTLIB)
aux_source_directory(./engine SRC_ENGINE)
aux_source_directory(./utils SRC_UTILS)

include_directories(./extlib)
include_directories(./engine)
include_directories(./utils)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(LONE_HEADERS ./engine/stc_config.h)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_ROOT} ${SRC_ENGINE} ${SRC_UTILS} ${LONE_HEADERS})

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2IMAGE REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

add_library(tinyxml2 SHARED ./extlib/tinyxml2.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES} tinyxml2)
```

**Edit:** I've checked which library files the binary is linked with using `ldd` command and the output confirms they are all shared libraries:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff9dbf0000)
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3accff7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3accdda000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f3accb59000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f3acc7fb000)
    libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3acc5d5000)
    libtinyxml2.so => /home/hacow/OGLTEST/libtinyxml2.so (0x00007f3acc3bd000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3acc0ae000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3acbda9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3acbb93000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3acb7f0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3acb5ec000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3acb3e4000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3acd2fa000)
    libnvidia-tls.so.349.16 => /usr/lib/libnvidia-tls.so.349.16 (0x00007f3acb1e1000)
    libnvidia-glcore.so.349.16 => /usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.349.16 (0x00007f3ac8472000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f3ac8130000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f3ac7f1e000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f3ac7cfc000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f3ac7af8000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f3ac78f2000)
```

Comment: Did you try building it without debugging information/symbols?

Comment: @RedAgito Yes the resulting binaries from debug and non-debug are 1.4 mb each. But debug version should be bigger.

Comment: And you are linking against the non-debug versions of the respective libraries?

Comment: There's no reference to debug versions in find scripts.

Comment: You might be linking against a version of the library/libraries that contain debugging informations. Otherwise I have not idea EDIT: It might be code bloat from templates and such, but 1.4 mb is a bit much

Comment: I didn't define my own templates but I use STL library templates such as `vector` and `unordered_map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building with `cmake .` uses the same `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` as the most recent build in that directory. Use `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .` to build in release mode. If you built debug first then release, using the procedure you described, it would just rebuild your debug binary.

Comment: Thanks it nailed the problem. Its a weird behavior on cmake's part and confusing, but afterall many things about cmake are confusing anyway.